# Lua flexible function argument unpacking in local function

Tags: lua, functional-programming, argument-unpacking

I am working on command handler that needs to work in two environments. Below is a a small part of the function I am working on, which I think captures the problem. At least, I get the error message I need to adress.

In the live environment, a Fibaro Home center 2, command sets given in the table should be executed one by one using `fibaro:call`, which takes 2-3 arguments, depending the call.

During development I instead use the `print` function to just print the commands that should have been issued.

```
function movementHandler(movementSendorId,onTable)
    local offTable = offTable or {};
    local onTable = onTable or {};
    if (fibaro or {}).call then 
       function callFunc(...) ;
          return fibaro:call(...);
       end;
    else
        function callFunc(...)
            print(unpack(arg));
       end;       
    end;
    if onTable ~= {} then
        for i,command in pairs(onTable) do
            callFunc(unpack(command));
        end;
    end;
end;
```

However, when I try this in the Lua command shell

```
> c= {}
> c[1] = {1,"turnOn"}
> c[2] = {1,"setValue",10}
> movementHandler(10,c,c)
```

, I get this output:

```
stdin:10: bad argument #1 to 'unpack' (table expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'unpack'
    stdin:10: in function 'callFunc'
    stdin:15: in function 'movementHandler'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

What I am not understanding about how `unpack` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic creation of the `arg` table for vararg functions was deprecated in Lua 5.1 and removed in Lua 5.2.

Use simply

```
function callFunc(...)
    print(...)
end
```

If you need a table, use

```
function callFunc(...)
    local arg={...}
    print(unpack(arg))
end
```

Comment: Fantastic! I am of course not "in" the Lua world enough for me to notice things like deprivation of functionality. Shame on me. :-) Thank you!

Comment: @Fredrik Lua Land is a Lovely Location :)

Comment: @warspyking - Lua Land has some "dark corners".  And its fauna has some *beginner-hateful* beasts running around.

Comment: Dark corners are fun. If there were no mysterious and/or hateful parts of real life it's be so boring @Egor